# Error when computing Gauss curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

Am trying to find constant negative Gauss curvature surface using parametrization  for a 2-D patch in 3-D space $$ (\sin u\, \cos v ,\sin u \,\sin v, f(v))$$

A solution obtained is $$ f(v) = c v \sin^2 u + d $$

c and d are constants. But it has an error ( back substitution K not constant), I am unable to find source of the same.

Please help to find it.